# Cannot connect to software update server

Tags: macos, software-update

By some reason I cannot connect to the software update server. I'm receiving the following message when I try to fetch the updates:

[image]

Can you suggest how I can switch to the native Apple update server? I used to be assigned to the corporate one before, but it's no longer the case. Any chance to change it without bringing my laptop to the Apple store?
The options suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29070/how-do-i-change-software-update-server-to-official-one-on-os-x-lion-or-later) didn't help. I keep receiving the same error.
OS version: macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check you're using the correct command - there were a few variants for different OS versions, but this will work for 10.10 onwards, including 10.12 Sierra:

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```